# How to run php interpreter remotely?

Tags: javascript, php, html, webserver

I'm trying to run php interpreter remotely in a html file. Basically the html file contains the php code which I want to execute it by using remote php interpreter via reference or something. I did it with other languages and it is working.

Like:

For JAVASCRIPT: (we directly write "javascript")

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("This is Javascript!")
</script>
```

For JQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```

For ANGULARjs:
(*I'm not sure it might be...*)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
```

Is there way to include the link for php too,
like something:

```
<script src="php.ini">
```

or

```
<script src="<path to php webserver of remote>">
</script>
```

Can anyone please tell me how it is possible or the way it can be get it done.

Comment: use [`include` or `require`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Comment: Inside your PHP file: `<?php include "external.php";` But you can only include local script, can't execute a script from remote sites.

Comment: Thanks Prasanth & Catcon, but I'm using html file, in which php code is there which I want to get it compile & execute it by providing as reference of php interpreter or something similar.

Comment: @David better use `.php` for php file instead of using `.html`.Its better way to handle hosting

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server and you wish to execute php in an html file, you will need to tell your server to execute .html files as .php with apache2 you need to add the below code snippet to .htaccess in the current working directory or a parent one, this will make all .html files get handeled as if they where a php script

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

I'm not entirely sure why you don't just use .php file extenstion, but hey there are many valid reasons...

One thing to note, all of the languages you posted are javascript based, javascript is a client side language, whereas php runs on the server. There is a HUGE difference between how they work.